# renormalization subtraction point, scaling

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

When we use minimal subtraction scheme, for instance, we have a dependence of coupling on a scale $\mu$. Using the $\beta$ function, we can observe the behavior of the coupling at different scale $\mu$. However, we say this scale $\mu$ is not really a 'physical' scale, and observable is independent of this scale. So doesn't this mean $\mu$ can be set to anything? If so, why can't we use perturbation in QCD for low-energy process, for instance? Can't we just set this arbitrary $\mu$ really high such that QCD calculation can be done perturbatively?

Please help me straighten out my confusion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $\mu$ can be anything. Usually in renormalization, we measure (or define) the coupling constant $g$ at scale $\mu$, and then use this information to predict the coupling constant $g'$ at another scale $\mu'$. We require that $g'$ at $\mu'$ is independent of $\mu$. What I mean is that you should get the same $g'$ at $\mu'$ even if you use another $g$ measure at another $\mu$ initially.

The reason that we cannot use perturbation in QCD in low-energy is that the coupling constant is large ($>1$), which makes the perturbation break down.

We can set $\mu$ very high, and get a $g$ at $\mu$, but that's QCD at high energy ($\mu$) now, not at low energy. At low energy, we should use the coupling constant at low energy.

Comment: but my question is how is $\mu$ related to physical energy scale? If it isn't, then why can't we talk about high $\mu$ for low physical energy process?

Comment: @Quantization $\mu$ is a physical energy scale. And in my answer, $g$ is the coupling constant at this scale $\mu$.

Comment: aha! making some sense now. so 'g' value computed experimentally from some physical scale $\mu$ gives you predictions about 'g' at different physical scale $\mu$?

Comment: @Quantization Yes.

Comment: When we are calculating the very first 'g', since its value is not determined theoretically, how do we know if it is too high to use perturbative method?

Comment: We should at least measure once to get $g$ at at specific scale $\mu$. Whether we can use perturbation theory or not depends one whether g is larger or smaller than 1.